# Best view to easily browse through and accept answers on past questions?

Tags: support, search, question-lists

I want to go through and clean up my questions by selecting the answers, what is the best view/page for me to go to in order to easily access them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I go to my profile and look through my questions there.

Though I like a modification of what's been mentioned here, for the Search box:

**user:13295 hasaccepted:0**

Comment: +1: Adding `hasaccepted:0` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

When I type this into the SO search box:

```
user:52738
```

I get a list of all my questions followed by all my answers. You just have to swap out the number with your user ID. This may be easier than going through the questions on your profile page, since the view tends to reset when you navigate away and back.

Comment: To lazy to look for it now but there is also an option to only show unanswered questions. I think

Comment: Not a fan of this answer; I get a list of all my answers and questions this way. I prefer profile ... However, the thing to add for determining questions with unaccepted answers in your search terms would be `isaccepted:0`

Comment: @John: Adding `isaccepted:0` to the search seems to only show *answers* to questions with no accepted answer. It doesn't show *questions* that have no accepted answer marked yet.

Comment: My bad; I meant `hasaccepted` -- which explains why the results didn't please me ... (still prefer the profile view though, but that's just me.)

Answer (score 0):

Improving on [Lance's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22453/351462), if you're logged in you can use the following.

> **user:me hasaccepted:0**